# How can i change type of received data?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, signalr

There is my client code in Unity:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using SignalR.Client._20.Hubs;
using SignalR.Client._20.Transports;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class SignalRHelper : MonoBehaviour {
    public string signalRUrl = "http://localhost:52527";

    public Text text;
    public InputField message;
    public GameObject testObj;


    private string _resault;


    private HubConnection _hubConnection = null;
    private IHubProxy _hubProxy;


    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("start()");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        Debug.Log("start() 1 second");

        StartSignalR();
    }

    void StartSignalR()
    {
        Debug.Log("StartSignalR");
        if (_hubConnection == null)
        {
            _hubConnection = new HubConnection(signalRUrl);
            Debug.Log(signalRUrl);
            _hubConnection.Error += HubConnection_Error;

            _hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateProxy("ChatHub");

            Subscription subscription = _hubProxy.Subscribe("synx");
            subscription.Data += ChangePosition;
            subscription = _hubProxy.Subscribe("broadcastMessage");
            subscription.Data += Chat;

            Debug.Log("_hubConnection.Start();");
            _hubConnection.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Singnal already connected...");
        }

        //Пришёл ответ с сервера (got answer from server)

    }
    private void ChangePosition(object[] obj)
    {
        Debug.Log("Prishlo");
        Debug.Log(obj[0] + "," + obj[1] + "," + obj[2]);

    }
    private void Chat(object[] obj)
    {
        Debug.Log(obj[1].ToString());
        _resault += obj[0] + ":" + obj[1] + System.Environment.NewLine;
    }

    //
    // Попробовать изменить на потоки
    //
    //


    private void Update()
    {
        text.text = _resault;
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E))
        {
            Debug.Log("hubProxy of cube: " + _hubProxy);
            _hubProxy.Invoke("Synx", testObj.transform.position.x,       testObj.transform.position.y, testObj.transform.position.z);
        }
    }
    private void HubConnection_Error(System.Exception obj)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hub Error = " + obj.Message +System.Environment.NewLine +     obj.InnerException +
        System.Environment.NewLine + obj.Data +
        System.Environment.NewLine + obj.StackTrace +
        System.Environment.NewLine + obj.TargetSite);
    }

    private void HubConnection_Closed()
    {
    Debug.Log("hubConnection_Closed()");
    }

    public void SendMessage()
    {
        _hubProxy.Invoke("Send", "UnityEpta", message.text);
    }

    //Если вышли с приложения нужно остановить Connection

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnApplicationQuit " + Time.time + "seconds");
        _hubConnection.Error -= HubConnection_Error;
        _hubConnection.
```

And it is in server:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
        public void Synx(Stock stock)
        {
            Clients.All.synx(stock);
        }
    }
    public class Stock
    {
        public float x { get; set; }
        public float y { get; set; }
        public float z { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I receive position of testObj in 'object' type, but i can't change position with 'object' type. I tried to change from 'object' to 'float', but nothing heppened.
Then i replaced 'private void ChangePosition(object[] obj)' to 'private void ChangePosition(float[] obj)', i got error, that there is can be only 'object' type.Method 'Convert.ChangeType' doesn't work. How can i change receive data to float or how can i change position of testObj 
in another ways?

Comment: Maybe try Convert.ToFloat(obj) ?

Comment: How about casting to Stock? It'd be easier to send a byte array or serialized data.

Comment: @Everts 
Can you tell me in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

**The method signature must match!**

(Means name of method and also number and type of parameters)

```
public void Synx(Stock stock)
```

matches not with :

```
_hubProxy.Invoke("Synx", testObj.transform.position.x,       testObj.transform.position.y, testObj.transform.position.z);
```

Why you do not add to another libray like mycontracts and reference it in your client and your server project.

Than you can

```
_hubProxy.Invoke("Synx", new Stock({...);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand about _hubProxy.Invoke("Synx", new Stock({...);

Comment: Your client must know the class stock. Method signature must match. Whats not clear about that?

Comment: I changed _hubProxy.Invoke("Synx", testObj.transform.position.x......); to  _hubProxy.Invoke("Synx", new Stock(testObj.transform.position.x,testObj.transform.position.y,testObj.transform.position.z)); But i got an error that Stock doesn't contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments. I added public 
Stock(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.x = 1;
        this.y = 1;
        this.z = 1;
    }
I receive "x: 160", but i need "160"

Comment: And it is object type too

Comment: Maybe you should write clearer what you rellay mean. Where do you need 160?